# Php server to server session management

Tags: php, apache, session

I am trying to retrive XML from a site and process on my server. I can get the XML on my browser after I log in to the specific site. but I cannot do it by sending request from directly from server because the session is not available. How can I achive this

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's using basic auth you should be able to do this with curl setting a auth_user /password: http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php